# Wrong Syntax error for date in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

What's wrong with this code?

```
if(Year(rs.Fields(created_date)) == Year(Now) AND Month(rs.Fields(created_date)) == Month(Now) AND Day(rs.Fields(created_date)) >= Day(Now) +3) {
```

It says, wrong syntax. How will I make this correct?

Comment: The code you posted is not VBScript. Looks like a mixture of JavaScript and VBScript elements. How are you running the code, and what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Invalid Character.Code: 800A0408

Comment: Which of my codes is in java script language.

Comment: Repeating myself: please show the *exact* error. Do *not* paraphrase. And how *exactly* are you running the code? As for which part is what: the `AND` operator and the date functions are VBScript, the `==` and curly braces are JavaScript (as Ekkehard.Horner already pointed out in his answer).

Comment: Unless you post all of the code as well as the full error text, it is difficult to effectively help.  However, above you have a squiggly bracket "{" at the end that can't be there and the double equal signs "==" need to be single "=".  Though that probably isn't really what you need to be doing.  You should use DateDiff to get your date comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The operator is `And`, not `&&`:

```
>> If True && False Then
>>    WScript.Echo "&& is not VBScript"
>> End If
>>
Error Number:       1002
Error Description:  Syntax error
>> If True And True Then
>>    WScript.Echo "&& is And"
>> End If
>>
&& is And
```

On second look: VBScript is not Javascript (==, {}).